# Improving MySQL Update Performance

Tags: mysql

I've got a process to import/update data from a CSV file. The process of saving that data from the csv to a "temp" table works fine. (temp_mls_transactions)

The next step is to update the existing records in the production table (tbl_mlsTransactions) with the data from the "temp" table. This step is causing the issue. ***IF*** it completes, its about 17 minutes for 7k records.

After the update is complete, we delete the common records from the "temp" table. Then insert the remaining records.

Here is the update query:

```
UPDATE tbl_MLSTransactions mt USE INDEX(idx_mlsNumber_association) INNER JOIN temp_mls_import temp USE INDEX (idx_mlsAssociationID_mlsID) ON mt.mlsNumber=temp.mlsNumber AND mt.mlsAssociationID=temp.mlsAssociationID
            SET mt.activeStatusDate=temp.activeStatusDate,
                mt.closeDate=temp.closeDate,
                mt.closePrice=temp.closePrice,
                mt.coListAgentMLSID=temp.coListAgentMLSID,
                mt.coSellingAgentMLSID=temp.coSellingAgentMLSID,
                mt.currentPrice=temp.currentPrice,
                mt.dateAvailable=temp.dateAvailable,
                mt.daysToClose=temp.daysToClose,
                mt.daysToContract=temp.daysToContract,
                mt.DOM=temp.DOM,
                mt.expectedClosingDate=temp.expectedClosingDate,
                mt.expirationDate=temp.expirationDate,
                mt.address=temp.address,
                mt.address2=temp.address2,
                mt.city=temp.city,
                mt.state=temp.state,
                mt.zip=temp.zip,
                mt.lastChangeType=temp.lastChangeType,
                mt.lastDateAvailable=temp.lastDateAvailable,
                mt.lastListPrice=temp.lastListPrice,
                mt.lastStatus=temp.lastStatus,
                mt.latitude=temp.latitude,
                mt.listAgentMLSID=temp.listAgentMLSID,
                mt.listPrice=temp.listPrice,
                mt.listingContractDate=temp.listingContractDate,
                mt.longitude=temp.longitude,
                mt.originalListPrice=temp.originalListPrice,
                mt.pendingDate=temp.pendingDate,
                mt.propertyStatus=temp.propertyStatus,
                mt.sellingAgentMLSID=temp.sellingAgentMLSID,
                mt.status=temp.status,
                mt.statusContractualSearchDate=temp.statusContractualSearchDate,
                mt.withdrawnDate=temp.withdrawnDate,
                mt.withdrawnStatus=temp.withdrawnStatus,

                mt.listOfficeMLSID=temp.listOfficeMLSID,
                mt.coListOfficeMLSID=temp.coListOfficeMLSID,
                mt.sellingOfficeMLSID=temp.sellingOfficeMLSID,
                mt.coSellingOfficeMLSID=temp.coSellingOfficeMLSID;
```

Here is the create statement for the "temp" table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_mls_import` (
  `tempID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activeStatusDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsFull` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsHalf` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bedsTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CDOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `closePrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coListAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coListOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coSellingAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coSellingOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contractStatus` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateAvailable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `daysToClose` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daysToContract` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expectedClosingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expectedLeaseDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expirationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expirationRenewalDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastChangeType` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastDateAvailable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastListPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastStatus` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `listAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `listOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `listPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listingContractDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `mlsNumber` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `offMarketDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `officePrimaryBoardID` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalEntryTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalListPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PDOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pendingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `photoCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCodePlus4` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceChangeTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `propertyStatus` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `propertyType` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `providerModificationTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `realtorComYN` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellingAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellingOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPLPRatio` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sqftHeated` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sqftTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusChangeTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusContractualSearchDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `teamName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tempOffMarketDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawnDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawnStatus` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearBuilt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mlsAssociationID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tempID`),
  KEY `idx_mlsAssociationID_mlsID` (`mlsNumber`,`mlsAssociationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And here is the create statement for the production table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_mlstransactions` (
  `transactionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activeStatusDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsFull` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsHalf` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathsTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bedsTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CDOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `closePrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coListAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coListOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coSellingAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coSellingOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contractStatus` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateAvailable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `daysToClose` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daysToContract` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expectedClosingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expectedLeaseDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expirationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expirationRenewalDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastChangeType` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastDateAvailable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastListPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastStatus` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `listAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `listOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `listPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listingContractDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `mlsNumber` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `offMarketDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `officePrimaryBoardID` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalEntryTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalListPrice` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PDOM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pendingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `photoCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCodePlus4` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceChangeTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `propertyStatus` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `propertyType` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `providerModificationTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `realtorComYN` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellingAgentMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellingOfficeMLSID` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPLPRatio` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sqftHeated` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sqftTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusChangeTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusContractualSearchDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `teamName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tempOffMarketDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawnDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawnStatus` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearBuilt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mlsAssociationID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  KEY `idx_agentListInfo` (`listAgentMLSID`(191),`coListAgentMLSID`(191),`closeDate`,`status`),
  KEY `idx_agentSellInfo` (`sellingAgentMLSID`(191),`coSellingAgentMLSID`(191),`closeDate`,`status`),
  KEY `IDX_listAgentMLSID` (`listAgentMLSID`(191)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_coListAgentMLSID` (`coListAgentMLSID`(191)),
  KEY `IDX_sellingAgentMLSID` (`sellingAgentMLSID`(191)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_coSellingAgentMLSID` (`coSellingAgentMLSID`(191)),
  KEY `idx_productionSearch` (`mlsAssociationID`,`status`,`closeDate`),
  KEY `idx_agentIDs` (`listAgentMLSID`(191),`coListAgentMLSID`(191),`sellingAgentMLSID`(191),`coSellingAgentMLSID`(191)),
  KEY `idx_closeDate` (`closeDate`),
  KEY `idx_mlsNumber_association` (`mlsNumber`,`mlsAssociationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4543783 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The import is not currently running, but here is the output from the explain statement on the update query

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,temp,NULL,ALL,idx_mlsAssociationID_mlsID,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,100.00,"Using where"
1,UPDATE,mt,NULL,ref,idx_mlsNumber_association,idx_mlsNumber_association,128,"agenttracker.temp.mlsNumber,agenttracker.temp.mlsAssociationID",1,100.00,NULL
```

Any suggestions on how to make this quicker?

**UPDATE:**

I ran a few different files and when the ID's (MlsNumber, AgentID's, etc) are shorter (i.e. 5-10 characters) the update completes in 0.25 seconds. When they are longer (i.e. 25-27 characters) is when there is a problem.
Here are a couple examples of the long and short MLS Numbers:

20191104230040909159000000

20191104230040909159000000

20191104230040909159000000

Short:

4PRW01

20593419

20698727

Comment: edit your question to show output of `show create table tbl_MLSTransactions` and `show create table temp_mls_import` and `explain UPDATE ...rest of your update statement` please

Comment: @ysth I just added the requested info. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is autocommit on? Please, in mysql console, run: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';` and provide the output here.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov - Yes it its on 'autocommit','ON'

Comment: If you turn it off, make the import as single transaction, then commit, and turn autocommit back on, it will speed up the process. Instead of n commits you will have only one.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShindarov. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98815/220955 But make sure to turn it off/on not globally but only for this connection.